# Determine the minimum bounding box to capture an object in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have background subtracted images as input.  The idea is to reduce search areas for person detection by using a smaller search area for the HOG algorithm.  The output required is a bounding box around the person and the pixel positions of the box corners.

This is the input image:

[image: input image]

This is the required output:

[image: required output]

This is what I have tried so far:

```
x=imread('frame 0080.png');   
y=im2bw(x);
s=regionprops(y);    

imshow(y);    
hold on

for i=1:numel(s)  
   rectangle('Position',s(i).BoundingBox,'edgecolor','y')
end
```

This was the output I got:

[image: actual output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have tried what I have suggested.  However, you want the bounding box that encapsulates the entire object.  This can easily be done by using the `BoundingBox` property, then calculating each of the four corners of each rectangle.  You can then calculate the minimum spanning bounding box that encapsulates all of the rectangles which ultimately encapsulates the entire object.

I do notice that there is a thin white strip at the bottom of your image, and that will mess up the bounding box calculations.  As such, I'm going to cut the last 10 rows of the image before we proceed calculating the minimum spanning bounding box.  To calculate the minimum spanning bounding box, all you have to do is take all of the corners for all of the rectangles, then calculate the minimum and maximum `x` co-ordinates and minimum and maximum `y` co-ordinates.  These will correspond to the top left of the minimum spanning bounding box and the bottom right of the minimum spanning bounding box.

When taking a look at the `BoundingBox` property using `regionprops`, each bounding box outputs a 4 element vector:

```
[x y w h]
```

`x,y` denote the top left co-ordinate of your bounding box.  `x` would be the column and `y` would be the row of the top left corner.  `w,h` denote the width and the height of the bounding box.  We would use this and compute top left, top right, bottom left and bottom right of every rectangle that is detected.  Once you complete this, stack all of these rectangle co-ordinates into a single 2D matrix, then calculate the minimum and maximum `x` and `y` co-ordinates.  To calculate the rectangle, simply use the minimum `x` and `y` co-ordinates as the top left corner, then calculate the width and height by subtracting the maximum and minimum `x` and `y` co-ordinates respectively.

Without further ado, here's the code.  Note that I want to extract all of the bounding box co-ordinates in a `N x 4` matrix where `N` denotes the number of bounding boxes that are detected.  You would have to use [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) to do this correctly:

```
% //Read in the image from StackOverflow
x=imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRWId.png');

% //Threshold and remove last 10 rows
y=im2bw(x);
y = y(1:end-10,:);

% //Calculate all bounding boxes
s=regionprops(y, 'BoundingBox');

%// Obtain all of the bounding box co-ordinates
bboxCoords = reshape([s.BoundingBox], 4, []).';

% // Calculate top left corner
topLeftCoords = bboxCoords(:,1:2);

% // Calculate top right corner
topRightCoords = [topLeftCoords(:,1) + bboxCoords(:,3) topLeftCoords(:,2)];

% // Calculate bottom left corner
bottomLeftCoords = [topLeftCoords(:,1) topLeftCoords(:,2) + bboxCoords(:,4)];

% // Calculate bottom right corner
bottomRightCoords = [topLeftCoords(:,1) + bboxCoords(:,3) ...
    topLeftCoords(:,2) + bboxCoords(:,4)];

% // Calculating the minimum and maximum X and Y values
finalCoords = [topLeftCoords; topRightCoords; bottomLeftCoords; bottomRightCoords];
minX = min(finalCoords(:,1));
maxX = max(finalCoords(:,1));
minY = min(finalCoords(:,2));
maxY = max(finalCoords(:,2));

% Draw the rectangle on the screen
width = (maxX - minX + 1);
height = (maxY - minY + 1);
rect = [minX minY width height];

% // Show the image
imshow(y);
hold on;
rectangle('Position', rect, 'EdgeColor', 'yellow');
```

---

This is the image I get:

[image]